# .Net Core EF migration succes but I can't find databases

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created .netcore mvc app. I installed tools

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

I created db context

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Book model

```
public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }

    }
```

in startup

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
                );
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(LocalDb)\\DESKTOP-FG2D20E;Database=BookListMVC;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
```

The management studio 18 entering
[image]

The problem is not migrating

```
PM> add-migration MyFirstMig
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.1.1 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
PM>
```

And in my management stuido there no database created. so whats the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrations are just versioned instructions for your database. Now that you created them you have to apply them to your database with this command:

```
PM> Update-Database
```

You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs#create-your-database-and-schema).

Comment: Well I tryed but now it gives this error. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
)

Comment: Do you have an appsettings.development.json file? That could be overwriting the connection string in your appsettings.json.

Comment: Yes I found it under appsettings.json then copy pasted to this file.They are identical now but it still gives same

Comment: Did you install a full version of SQL Server? Because my SQL Server Express installation reads as "(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB" in Management Studio. Please try the connection string "Server=DESKTOP-FG2D20E;Database=BookListMVC;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" or "Server=localhost;Database=BookListMVC;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True".

Comment: Thank you friend. Now it creates table in database